# Unexpected behavior from mongoose js when using JSON.stringify(queryObject)

Tags: javascript, json, express, mongoose

When I do `JSON.stringify({theKey : 'some\thing'}`, the result will be:

```
{"theKey" : "some\\thing"}
```

But with `queryObject` returned from mongoose query, `JSON.stringify(queryObject)` will not add the second backslash so when I parse it on the other end it give me error. Thank you

Comment: the result will be `{"theKey" : "some\\thing"}, but with ...

Comment: If you surround the code parts back ticks \` <code> \` it will be highlighted

Comment: Are you seeing the extra `\` when inspecting in a REPL or the console? It's not actually in the JSON. The JSON value is also `"some\thing"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misinterpreting the internal representation of the JSON (maybe from the console?) as JSON.

`\` starts an escape sequence in JS [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) defined inside `"`, `'` or a backtick, which means the character following it may have special meaning. To get JS to actually output a `\` in a string. You need two slashes.

```
> console.log('\\')
\
```

JSON encoding needs to output the escape sequence with the `\` rather than a literal tab character. This means the internal representation has two `\\`s. When you use the string it looks ok:

```
> console.log(JSON.stringify({theKey : 'some\thing'}))
{"theKey":"some\thing"}
```

The [escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_notation) which have special meaning are:

`\0` null
`\b` backspace 
`\f` form feed
`\n` newline
`\t` tab
`\r` carriage return 
`\v`  vertical tab 
`\xNN` unicode
`\uNN` unicode
`\"`
`\'`

Here are some more examples of the differences between internal representations and actual JSON output

```
> a = JSON.stringify("a\az")
'"aaz"'
> console.log(a)
"aaz"

> b = JSON.stringify("a\bz")
'"a\\bz"'
> console.log(b)
"a\bz"

> s = JSON.stringify("a\\z")
'"a\\\\z"'
> console.log(s)
"a\\z"
```